# How to GroupBy on Telerik RadGrid from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've seen you can do **GroupByExpressions** on Telerik's RadGrid like this:

```
<GroupByExpressions>
   <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
      <SelectFields>
         <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="Received" FieldName="Received" FormatString="{0:D}"
          HeaderValueSeparator=" from date: "></telerik:GridGroupByField>
      </SelectFields>
      <GroupByFields>
         <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Received" SortOrder="Descending"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
      </GroupByFields>
   </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
</GroupByExpressions>
```

But I'm trying to group employees **from code**. I've tryed this (employeelist have 27 rows):

```
Telerik.Web.UI.GridGroupByExpression groupby = new Telerik.Web.UI.GridGroupByExpression();

groupby.SelectFields.FindByName("EmployeeSoc");
groupby.GroupByFields.FindByName("EmployeeSoc");
gridEmployees.MasterTableView.GroupByExpressions.Add(groupby);

gridEmployees.PageSize = employeelist.Count();
gridEmployees.DataSource = employeelist;

grdDatos.Rebind();
```

Nothing goes wrong during the debug, but grid says 'No records to display.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a [programmatic definition of a group by expression](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/grouping/group-by-expressions/programmatic-definition) in RadGrid.

There are three things I see that might be incorrect with the code you have posted.  Try to take a look at each and reach a possible solution or move you along past your current error:

1. You have not defined an Aggregate Function.  Each grouping needs to have an aggregate function (Sum, Avg, Max, Min, etc)
2. Your list is not wired into your RadGrid correctly.  When I see the error

> No records to display

this is means no rows from the List are displayed regardless of the groupings.  Remove the grouping code and get the employees displaying correctly without groupings in your RadGrid.

3. Your `SelectField` "EmployeeSoc" is the same as your `GroupByField`.  This is okay to do - but typically one likes to group one column against the other. (Price per Product, or Average Age per category, etc)

Please post your data model in your question and your grouping goal from a requirements perspective with EmployeeList and we can try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your link! I follwed it all and now it works. Only one more think, how can I show groups unexpanded?

Comment: I solved this for my work project last week.  If you post this as a new question on SO and then comment here, I will go to the question and answer it for you.

Comment: Hi! No problem I've been watching documentation before and I found it. Thanks!